# How to determine polar coordinate visually

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am studying calculating arc length on polar coordinates on khan academy and I encounter this question.

> Let R be circular segment that lies inside the circle $r=4cos(\theta)$
>   and the left of $r=sec(\theta)$.
>
> Calculate the perimeter of the shaded region.

[image: You should look at this picture]

I know how to use formula, and I familiar with polar coordinates. However, when I encountered this I set boundaries for my integral as $\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3$! Which is wrong. so after struggling a lot and realizing that I am doing things wrong, by solving this equation $4cos(\theta)=sec(\theta)$ I realized that I must set my boundaries as $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$. The lower boundary is apparent by the diagram, but the other one seems strange to me!

In the hints there is this line:

> The entire circle is traced out once from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi$ thus the arc is traced from $\theta=\pi/3$ to $\theta=2\pi/3$

Unfortunately, I am not even able to understand what this hint even is about! 
So my questions are:
How can I determine boundaries visually from the diagram and what this hint talk about? the circle must be traced out from $0$ to $2\pi$, why it says $\pi$??

Comment: Notice that the way polar coordinates work, the circle $r=4*\cos (\theta)$ is actually drawn twice during the period $0 \to 2\pi$. The two circles that are drawn just happen to overlap, resulting in only one that is seen.

Comment: Imagine you are a lighthouse at the origin.  You swing your light from 0 to... whatever it is that you first see the endpoint of the arc. ... there it is.  You hit the endpoint of the arc at pi/3.  You trace the arc with you light for pi/3 to pi/2. While you do this you distance of the arc goes from 2 down to 0. At pi/2 the distance stops being positive and starts being negative.  That's okay,your light bean goes both ways. You continue to trace the arc until you get to the endpoint. That happens at 2pi/3. You are done. If you continue going you hit the endpoint *again* and you trace it twice.

Comment: "your light beam goes both ways"  for pi/2 to 2pi/3 the arc is *behind* you.  (i.e. $r \le 0$. If you were tracing the circle you'd start with theta = 0 => (0,4)  at theta = pi/4 => (2,2) and theta = pi/2 => (0,0) that's the top half of the circle.  from theta = pi/2 => (0,0) through theta = 3pi/4 => (2,-2) to theta = pi => (0, 4) you have traced the entire circle. If we go from theta = pi to theta = 2pi we will trace the circle TWICE. So in the full theta 0 - 2pi we would trace the arc TWICE. We only want to trace it once.  the arc first comes into scope at pi/3 and leaves our scope at 2pi/3.

Comment: @JohnLou I have studied at khan academy and I am pretty sure I haven't skipped anything but what you say seems strange to me. why circle is drawn twice?

Comment: @fleablood thanks. now I have an idea about how to determine boundaries visually, but I have no Idea why my light beam goes both ways. Can you a explain your comment a little more, and write it as an answer?? I am a little confused

Comment: Consider that for $\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi$, $r$ is negative!! For $\theta=2\pi/3$ you have, $r=-2$, so is, the formula says that the point for $\theta=2\pi/3$ is in the fourth quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the perimeter using regular geometry.

Using the angle markings, we can deduce that the perimeter of the curved part is a third of the perimeter of the circle. Connecting the $\frac13 \pi$ and the $\frac53 \pi$ lines to the circle's center, we form two equilateral triangles. Their angles added together must be $\frac23 \pi$. Therefore, the perimeter of the curved part is $\frac23 \pi r = \frac43 \pi$. After drawing altitudes from the top to the bottom side on both of the equilateral triangles and using special 30-60-90 triangle rules, we see that half of the line is $\sqrt{3}$, so the whole line is $2\sqrt{3}$. Adding these together we get the perimeter as $\boxed{\frac43 \pi + 2\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: There is an error here because $r=2$ for circle in question

Comment: @CyeWaldman I fixed the issue, the answer's right now.

Comment: Thank you but my question is how to determine boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a different view here and will determine the perimeter by analysis in the complex plane. We will divide the problem in to two parts, the circular arc and the straight line. These can be readily shown to be described by

$$
r=4\cos\theta,\quad \theta\in[\pi/3,2\pi/3]\\
r=\sec\theta,\ \quad \theta\in[-\pi/3,2\pi/3]
$$

The general equation for the arc length in the complex plane is

$$s=\int |\dot z| du\color{gray}{=\int\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}\ dx}$$

We start with the arc...

$$
z=4\cos\theta\ e^{i\theta}\\
\dot z=(-4\sin\theta+i\cos\theta)\ e^{i\theta}\\
|\dot z|=4\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}=4\\
\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}4d\theta=\frac{4\pi}{3}
$$

The straight line can be much simpler than this, but here we are demonstrating a method. Thus,

$$
z=\sec\theta\ e^{i\theta}\\
\dot z=(\tan\theta \sec\theta+i\sec\theta)\ e^{i\theta}\\
|\dot z|=\sec\theta\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}=\sec^2\theta\\
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}\sec^2\theta\ d\theta=\tan\theta\big|_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}=2\sqrt{3}
$$

Thus, the total perimeter is given by

$$\boxed{s=\frac{4 \pi}{3} + 2\sqrt{3}}$$

This result has been verified numerically.